# Cookie / Session Value lost on deletion

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have made a shopping cart website where on updation of the cart increases or decreases the quantity column of my product table. For example, suppose I have 10 tshirts on my product table. A person adds 4 to his cart. So the number of t-shirts now in the table is 6.

But there is a problem here.. Since I am doing this using Session , when the browser is closed, the `session['cart'][$productid]['quantity']` gets lost, and although the person hasn't yet bought the 4 tshirts he added to cart, the quantity cannot be retrieved in the product column. That means my product column will have 6 tshirts instead of 10 though no one has bought 4 and the cart of the user is lost too..

This is also a problem with cookie..Suppose somebody deleted all browser cookies he has unknowingly or knowingly, the quantity is lost here too..

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be reducing the inventory count until he completes the purchase. You should only reduce the inventory after he has done a checkout. You can go ahead and have the cart in the cookie ,and do an inventory check just before he checksout and if the inventory available is less than the qty he has added in the cart , then show a message saying that the required qty is not available and if it is available proceed to checkout

Comment: then how am I supposed to check whether a user can add more product to his cart or not? Let a user adds 20 products to his cart , then on purchase it's found out that only 10 products are available.. then what?

Comment: I don't think that is a very good solution.. That is making the customer disappointed.. He adds so much keeping in mind of buying.. then comes the restriction...

Comment: Well its a double edged sword , say a customer just adds it to his cart but never purchases it , then what ? your items are in oblivion right ? Ok ... Another suggestion is to have an ajax call to poll the inventory at regular intervals , if there is a purchase that has happened and the inventory goes below what the user has put in his cart , then alert the user immediately , thereby he will have a better experience and IMHO you should reduce the inventory only after a purchase

Comment: polling? is it good for my RAM usage? polling at regular interval is the worst nightmare for wasting resources..

Comment: Agreed polling is bad , there are other options to polling like making use of Atmosphere Framework or long polling using Node.js which will help you.